# Windows 7 - Preview other file types as text in Preview Pane

Tags: windows-7

I want to preview `.js`, `.php`, and other file extensions as text in explorer on Windows 7.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: In the meantime, check out: http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/add-file-types-to-windows-7-preview-pane

Comment: 1. Press "Win" key 2. Type `cmd` 3. Press "Ctrl+Shift+Enter" 4. Copy `reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\.php /v PerceivedType /t REG_SZ /d text` 5. Paste in CMD with right click 6. Press "Enter" 7. Repeat from step 4, replacing `php`  with `js`. *Note: If insufficient privileges, replace `HKLM` with `HKCU`*

Answer (score 70, accepted):

On top of using [PreviewConfig](http://www.winhelponline.com/utils/previewconfig.zip), you will also have to add [entries into the registry](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/add-file-types-to-windows-7-preview-pane) to get it working on Windows 7.

- Open the registry editor (regedit in the start menu search) and navigate to `computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.FILE_EXT`, where `FILE_EXT` is the extension you want to add, such as `.nfo`

  [image]
- Make 2 new string values (`REG_SZ`) under the file extension's key, **Content Type** and **PerceivedType**

  [image]
- Set the value of `Content Type` to **text/plain** and `PerceivedType` to **text**.

---

Comment: On Win 7, I got not success on .m3u using PreviewConfig http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/9910/regionuj.png or the manual method too http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/3674/registryeditor.png . Any ideas?

Comment: I am not totally sure but it is not Perceived Type, it is PerceivedType

Comment: Success!! Per the answer below for most file types I did not need to manually edit the registry but for .config files I did because it had already been registered as ContentType application/xml and did not want to update. Thanks!

Comment: Note well (I should have): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_before_E_except_after_C

Comment: I have found this method (registry fix) works for .eml files without bothering with PreviewConfig at all - Windows 8.1.

Comment: This method also works for text formats on Windows 7 Professional without needing PreviewConfig.

Comment: How can I do that for the files without an extension?

Answer (score 32):

I just went to `RegEdit> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Classes`

Found `.log`

Added a new String Value with Value Name `PerceivedType` and Value Data `text`.

Started working straight away.

Comment: where did you get this tutorial from? please consider adding your source.

Comment: The benefit of this method is that if you change the viewer for the underlying type all types that are perceived as it will change too.

Comment: This worked for Windows 10 also and was very easy to do.

Comment: Perfect! I wanted to do this for markdown files on Windows 10. Went to the same location and looked for `.md` and added the same thing (PerceivedType: text). Voila, it worked right away.

Comment: It works also for adding new key with arbitrary extension name, if the extension doesn't exist. In my case, it was unregistered *.cff* file type. Tested on Windows 7.

Comment: My `.html` folder there in `Classes` unfortunately already has "Content Type" = "text/html" and "PerceivedType" = "text", but the previews don't work. I just see a Chrome icon.

Comment: Perfect, just what I wanted... now figure out a way to get formatting in that preview and it'd be awesome :)

Comment: Note, it doesn't need to be HKLM, it can be just per user HKCU.

Comment: If anyone wants a powershell 1-liner: `[microsoft.win32.registry]::SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.js", "PerceivedType", "text")` credit: [@Dubas on a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56114994/135114)

Comment: For .log on Win10, it did not work for me under HKCU.  I had to set it under HKLM.

Answer (score 19):

As of June 2010, [PreviewConfig](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/previewconfig-tool-registers-file-types-for-the-preview-pane-in-windows-vista/) will handle Windows 7 file preview duties without the need for any manual registry editing.

Answer (score 12):

You can solve this by using a little tool created by a Microsoft guy (Stephen Toub) called "PreviewHandlerEditor.exe", which is available here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/12/14/preview-handler-association-editor.aspx

Download and open the tool, uncheck "Only show classes associated with this handler", select a registered preview handler from the dropdown menu (e.g. "Windows TXT Previewer"), scroll through the list of classses/extensions, and select the file type you are having trouble previewing in Windows search.

I found this answer via: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/no-preview-available-there-are-several-files-that/9a93872f-db8e-450a-96b1-951a3d687fd9?page=2&tm=1423925169058#LastReply

Direct download link to app: https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00/01/28/65/88/PreviewHandlerEditor.zip

Comment: I find this tool to be more capable than the one in the accepted answer. It allows me to add and remove handlers from filetypes without limitation.  Thanks, @Michael for the link to the download - the links in Toub's original blog posting no longer work.

Comment: no need for tools.  windows provides it check out the solution here [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1320812/how-to-make-windows-explorer-preview-scripts-and-other-text-files/1321134#1321134)

Comment: The blog post appears to be gone, but the direct download link still works. Thanks

Comment: blog post is gone, and direct link does not work anymore, all links are dead.

Answer (score 5):

To view .ai in windows 7 preview handler

1. Navigate to .ai folder in the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes.ai
2. Under that make a key named `ShellEx` if not already there
3. Under ShellEx create a key name `{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}`
4. Under this new key change the data value to `{DC6EFB56-9CFA-464D-8880-44885D7DC193}` (I would have posted an image but Im not allowed to by the system but I'm sure you got it!)

[image]

Now even Adobe Illustrator files show up in the preview handler and you look like a Pro! This is possible as the preview handler for PDF files and AI files are the same so all that is being done is copy/paste the PDF one to the AI one!

Answer (score 2):

Try please:

[PreviewConfig Tool Registers File Types for the Preview Pane in Windows 7/Vista](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/previewconfig-tool-registers-file-types-for-the-preview-pane-in-windows-vista/)

Comment: Could you summarize your article here? We prefer you don't just link your own site as an answer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer:
If you don’t have the privilege to add a key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.log` (e.g. on a computer in an office environment):

You can create the same keys under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.log`

Worked for me with Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Using `powershell`

`[microsoft.win32.registry]::SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.js", "PerceivedType", "text")`

Thanks to Daryn's comment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm too lazy to looking for the .ext(the extension file i want). So, i do:

Go to Regedit(i do with Windows+R hotkey and 'regedit' input) and set the quick view as text like above answer

Go...
RegEdit> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Classes
and ...

After that, export and save(ex: log.reg) this config with right-click menu
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37T4j.png)

So, with another file extention you can edit(and save) above log.reg with your wanna .ext
Examle for .less file

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes.**less**]
@="txtfile"
"PerceivedType"="text"

Double click this file to apply effect.

Note: I think yo should do it your self because some(strange) .reg can be harm for your system

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do with PowerShell.

An example that sets text preview for **.js** extension:

```batch
Set-ItemProperty Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js -Name PerceivedType -Value text
Set-ItemProperty Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js -Name 'Content Type' -Value 'text/plain'
```

or if you want to set it for multiple extensions (**.js** and **.php** for example):

```batch
'.js', '.php' | % { 
    Set-ItemProperty Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\$_ -Name PerceivedType -Value text
    Set-ItemProperty Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\$_ -Name 'Content Type' -Value 'text/plain'
}
```