# Get Explorer preview for .eml files in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, email, windows-explorer

Is there an application or plug-in that allows viewing `.eml` E-Mail dumps (that may contain HTML and attachments) in Windows 7's preview pane?

I'm aware of the possibility of [adding the file type in the registry](https://superuser.com/questions/91804/windows-7-preview-other-file-types-as-text-in-preview-pane) but that will give only a plain-text view of the files, not a parsed view.

HTML viewing is a must for what I need, attachments are optional.

Is there some top-notch E-Mail client that introduces this functionality?

Is there a generic way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my Vista x32 the preview of .eml files works fine in Windows Explorer.

In my case, this may be because the .eml file-type is associated with Thunderbird version 2.

If the Preview pane doesn't show for your folder, you will have to customize its type.

If you are using Windows 64-bit and have installed Thunderbird 32-bit, then you should know that you have two versions of Explorer : 32-bit and 64-bit. By default, you use of course the 64-bit version, while Thunderbird 32-bit has installed its handler into the 32-bit version of Explorer. If you cannot find a 64-bit version of Thunderbird, the 32-bit Explorer can be invoked by the following :

```
%Systemroot%\SysWOW64\explorer.exe /separate
```

If the Thunderbird installation worked correctly, you may find that it can display .eml files.

Comment: Interesting, my eml is supposed to be associated with Thunderbird as well! I will double-check whether something is wrong with that.

Comment: Are you on Windows 64-bits ?

Comment: @harrymc yes, I am. Aha! Is that the reason why it doesn't work for me? Looks likely. Off to install the 64-bit version.

Comment: There is only an unofficial 64 bit binary for Thunderbird. I don't want to put that on top of my current (working) install. I will try this out on a different machine later. As I think it is *highly* likely this is the reason why it doesn't work for me, I'll award the bounty. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the bounty, and I have added some more info above.

Comment: @harrymc excellent! It turns out 64 bit Thunderbird has a *lot* of downsides -  among other things, no plugin support. But seeing as I just need this for one evening of sorting through a lot of `.eml` files, the "start Explorer in 32 bit mode" tip does it for me - didn't know that was possible. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a plug in, but have a look at this software

http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Email_Tools/Misc__Mail_Tools/EML_Viewer.html

Comment: "standalone utility"