# Preview eml files with Thunderbird?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, thunderbird

Is there a way to use Thunderbird to preview eml files in the Windows Explorer?

I have seen this topic but it doesn't answer the question : [Get Explorer preview for .eml files in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/188035/get-explorer-preview-for-eml-files-in-windows-7)

Comment: `Is there a way to use Thunderbird to preview files in Explorer`.... What ?

Comment: @Dave: Windows Explorer supports shell extensions which provide previews for file types, e.g. Adobe Reader generates thumbnails for PDFs.

Comment: @grawity, I understand that. I understand using Windows to preview .eml files. I don't understand how to use Thunderbird within Windows Explorer :(

Comment: Does Thunderbird provide a preview handler for the eml files in the Windows Exporer ?

Comment: Here is an image of the explorer with the built-in PreviewHandler of eml files. I would like to find another one as the built-in one is not really great. http://www.heberger-image.fr/data/images/87178_explorer.jpg