# is there a utility to peek into text files without opening on windows 7

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 - Preview other file types as text in Preview Pane](https://superuser.com/questions/91804/windows-7-preview-other-file-types-as-text-in-preview-pane)

so many times, i have to open config files to confirm they have correct settings.

it would be awesome if there was a quicker way to to see what's inside without having to load the file into a text editor, and than close it.

I am curious if anyone has come across this problem, and if any utilities exist that could offer quick peek on right lick ? i tried a few google searches but nothing interesting came up

Comment: What could be simpler? Can you explain more? Do you want a program that can give a precis?

Comment: From a command line: Cat foo.ini

Comment: i'd have to open command line to that location, and than type it out.. how's that quicker than just right click > open in editor ?

Comment: @Xavierjazz looking for a utility to peek into a text file while in windows UI w/out having to open the file in some editor

Comment: @SonicSoul It's not, but nothing really is. That is why it was a comment not an answer.

Comment: So right clicking and selecting edit is too much for you? I'm not sure what you are envisioning? Some sort of mind meld where you think at it and the file is dumped to your brain?

Comment: @EBGreen hah.. yah i guess im trying to shortcut a very short process :)  but yah.. i usually have a text editor already open with 10-20 tabs, and this just opens another one i have to worry about closing right after.. would be nice to have a quick peek w/out opening anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Windows Explorer you can press Alt-P to bring up the preview pane that shows you previews of txt files (and various other file types) out of the box. As for text files that have a different suffix, this has been answered in [Windows 7 - Preview other file types as text in Preview Pane](https://superuser.com/questions/91804/windows-7-preview-other-file-types-as-text-in-preview-pane)

Comment: EXACTLY what i was looking for. i was not aware of this cool hack, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's always findstr if you're looking for a command-line utility.

http://www.computerhope.com/findstr.htm

This would allow you to search multiple docs to find out if any of them have the value you're looking for.

If you're looking for something like a preview pane... Dolphin maybe?  Previews are generally used for pictures as they're easier to verify by thumbnail.  text not so much.  You'd either need to find an embedded editor or a file manager that supports this.

Comment: that's a cool util!  not really what i was looking for.. i'm just trying to preview what's in a specific file.. but always good to find new tools :)