# How may I get Explorer to preview .m3u files as text?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, preview

How may I get Explorer to preview .m3u files as text? I have tried [Windows 7 - Preview other file types as text in Preview Pane](https://superuser.com/questions/91804/windows-7-preview-other-file-types-as-text-in-preview-pane) and carefully checked, but no joy.

I got no success with .m3u using PreviewConfig:

[image: 1]

or the manual method too:

[image: 2]

Comment: I assume you have tried to use the suggested tool, PreviewHandlerEditor.exe, as per the linked question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Media Jukebox, uncheckmark the m3u File Association

[image]

The clue that led me here was the Note in the PreviewConfig image above - despite that nothing on that Media Jukebox dialog suggests the association affects more than Open, and Open on a .m3u does not invoke Media Jukebox, but instead Textpad.

Oddly, recheckmarking the File Association does not restore the issue i.e. preview continues to work.

Answer (score 5):

1. Start >> Regedit.exe
2. Find `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.m3u` key and check the 'Default' setting (in my case `VLC.m3u`)

[image]

3. Find `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VLC.m3u` (in this path substitute `VLC.m3u` with the value of your default setting in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.m3u`)
4. Create a new key in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VLC.m3u`: `shellex`
5. `Then in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VLC.m3u\shellex` also a new key: `{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}`, so it should look like this:

[image]

7. The `{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}` key tells Windows that you want to use a preview handler, now you only should specify which one you want to use.
   Set `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VLC.m3u\{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f} Default` to this value: `{1531d583-8375-4d3f-b5fb-d23bbd169f22}` (text handler ID)
8. If you want to use other handlers in shell you can find their ID's in the following key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PreviewHandlers`

Comment: Thanks, but that failed. http://i.imgur.com/RhpBmly.png , http://i.imgur.com/3hOWllR.png , http://i.imgur.com/sDoaOeb.png . I was surprised to see Media Jukebox there., because .m3u Open launches Textpad.

Comment: @ChrisJJ That is beacause you've already modified you registry with Previewconfig (and possibly you manually edited it, too). Revert to the original settings, and only apply the modifications I suggested. This way it should work. Moreover you have no settings in your .m3u key Content Type, and PerceivedType which should be 'audio/x-mpegurl' and 'audio' respectively. When a file's content cannot be determined windows handles it as text by default.

Comment: I made those changes http://i.imgur.com/UmF5rea.png. I don't know the original settings. Would you like to add the further required settings to your solution?

Comment: try deleting the three 'MediaJukebox.14.xxx' keys. (these were probably made by Previewconfig) Otherwise I have no further idea :D

Comment: Done http://i.imgur.com/hP18siK.png but no joy. Thanks anyway for trying.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't help

Answer (score -1):

right click the file -- > open with --> choose notepad from the list of programs, then put a checkmark in the "open future files with this program" (or whatever it says to that effect)

Comment: Thanks, but that does not affect the preview.

Comment: whoops! missed that... not sure on how to change the preview... sorry.