# Get Explorer preview to show .M3U file

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

How may I get Explorer preview to show an .M3U file as it if were a .TXT file?

Currently it does not:

[image: http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img907/1403/vjAoMq.png]

I have tried a registry hack that work for other text file types, but it did not work for .M3U.

I got no success with .m3u using PreviewConfig:

[image: 1]

or with the manual method:

[image: 2]

Comment: Does [this solution](http://superuser.com/a/91809/8672) work for you?

Comment: Thanks, but as my comment there says, no. I just tried again. Still no: http://i.imgur.com/RvN7VVL.png

Comment: Does it also not work when booting Windows in Safe mode?

Answer (score -1):

- Right Click on Mouse
- Hit Open with
- Choose Default Programs
  check box : Always use the selected, etc
- Select Notepad
- Click Ok

Comment: Thanks, but that fails here. http://i.imgur.com/C3gAbR4.png