# Windows 10 File Explorer Preview Pane blocks itself

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, preview-pane

As soon as I select a file, it shows the content in the preview pane, and is then immediately replaced with the message "This file can't be previewed because it is in use." If I click to disable and then re-enable the Preview pane button in the ribbon, the content appears as it should.  I find this happens with .html files, .txt files, and for other files where I added the PerceivedType=text registry entry as per [How can I get a file preview in file explorer in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/970951/how-can-i-get-a-file-preview-in-file-explorer-in-windows-10?noredirect=1&lq=1)
It behaves correctly when selecting .xlsx, .doc files.  I even tried installing  3rd party file-unlockers, but they report that the file is not locked. I also checked the file properties to check they were not locked because they were downloaded; these are files that I have created myself.

Any ideas on what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was given this from MS support which works, for a few months at least.
Click the Start button and type the word CMD, click select Run as administrator, enter the following commands one by one followed by the Enter key:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
DISM.exe /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup
sfc /scannow
```