# Have Windows Explorer preview markdown files

Tags: windows-explorer, markdown

The Windows explorer.exe has a previsualization pane (W7+) that let you preview .txt, .docx, .bat, etc. documents.

How can I make it preview markdown .md files ? Rendering just as plain text is kinda ok, but I'd like to render the markdown in the preview as well

Comment: Dupe of [Windows 7 - Preview other file types as text in Preview Pane](https://superuser.com/q/91804) (I don't have any close votes left).

Comment: Hmm actually this question is more specific towards markdown. I am not only looking to add it as a preview (like in the aforementionned question), but also to render the markdown in the preview if possible.

Comment: I'm _glad_ this question was not closed, because the other question does not have the answer by TaZi pointing to MS PowerToys. For me, MS PowerToys was the fastest and easiest way to get File Explorer in Windows 10 to preview Markdown files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, but, the solution to your problem is the correct answer from this thread: [Windows 7 - Preview other file types as text in Preview Pane](https://superuser.com/questions/91804/windows-7-preview-other-file-types-as-text-in-preview-pane)

Edit: Actually, according to [this guy](https://superuser.com/a/251198/402422) in that same thread, using [PreviewConfig](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/previewconfig-tool-registers-file-types-for-the-preview-pane-in-windows-vista/) should be enough.

Edit 2: In order to preview custom or non-standard file-types with actual rendering (eg. color for code, rendering markdown, or images), it seems you need to have a [Preview Handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/cc144143%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). [This](http://forums.apricitysoftware.com/t/windows-preview-handler-for-markdown-preview/341) thread on another forum adds some useful information to the discussion of developing such a preview handler, particularly [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/533948/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Preview-Handlers) written in C#. I tried searching for a pre-written .md preview handler, but have come back empty handed. If you know C# I highly suggest looking further into this.

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't have enough reputation to flag the question for closing, but you are absolutely right, I should've flagged it, maybe "in need of moderator intervention" saying the question is/was a dupe would be more appropriate for a pleb like me? Now that the question has been edited slightly I'm not sure anymore, however.

Comment: Don't worry about it. As you say the OP has commented on the proposed dupe ;)

Comment: Hehe. You found exactly the same links I was just looking at ;) Much better answer!

Comment: By the way. You now have enough rep to comment if you need to...

Comment: :D! Search engines are amazing. Oh hey look at that, woop woop!

Answer (score 7):

since a couple of days this is possible with the [MS PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases/tag/v0.16.0).

> Microsoft PowerToys is a set of utilities for power users to tune and streamline their Windows experience for greater productivity. Inspired by the Windows 95 era PowerToys project, this reboot provides power users with ways to squeeze more efficiency out of the Windows 10 shell and customize it for individual workflows. A great overview of the Windows 95 PowerToys can be found [here](https://socket3.wordpress.com/2016/10/22/using-windows-95-powertoys/).

After you have installed it, you just toggle on the option "File Explorer" on and you get the rendering you want. Links are not clickable yet and images don't show, but apart from that it looks nice.

It comes under an MIT license and can do other useful stuff.

Comment: sry, just took a bad example from the previous answer. I hope the current version is better.

Comment: Much better... :)

Answer (score 4):

Bit of an old thread, but this (a bit unstable) extension (warning: I am the author) does the trick for me:

https://github.com/Atrejoe/MarkdownPreview

Installation is a bit of a drag though.