# Why is Windows 10 Explorer preview pane not showing regular TXT files?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, preview-pane

My Windows 10 preview pane in Explorer is not showing the preview for regular `.txt` files. It simply displays `No preview available`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Verify the registry is correct: https://superuser.com/questions/91804/windows-7-preview-other-file-types-as-text-in-preview-pane

Comment: @Ramhound The registry is correct. I had already checked it according to that question before deciding to post this question. :/

Answer (score 3):

Much late, but you just need to modify the registry:

Copy everything between the --- and the bottom --- and save it as
restore_txt_preview.reg then double-click it, and answer yes or okay to everything.

--- start copy below this line

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt]
@="txtfile"
"ContentType"="text/plain"
"PerceivedType"="text"   

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\PersistentHandler]
@="{1531d583-8375-4d3f-b5fb-d23bbd169f22}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\ShellNew]
"ItemName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,6e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,2c,00,\
  2d,00,34,00,37,00,30,00,00,00
"NullFile"=""
```

--- end copy before this line

Comment: Sorry, the formatting on this page moved the Windows Registry editor line to the same one as the "copy from here" but it is where you should begin copying the text.

Comment: You should edit your answer and make sure it’s formatted

Comment: Windows Explorer only shows previews for bitmap files for me, but not for documents like Word, PDF, Text. Grateful for any other ideas on how this could be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

> Hold down the Windows key and type `r`
>
> Type `regedit`, then hit enter
>
> Choose HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes
>
> Scroll down until you find `.txt`
>
> Right-click and choose New -> String Value
>
> Type `PerceivedValue` and hit enter
>
> Right-click the new entry you just created, and choose `Modify..`
>
> In the "Value Data" box, type `text` and hit enter