# How to control what file types to preview in Windows 10 preview pane?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Presently, all documents (txt, docx, pdf, ...), raster images (jpg, tiff, png, ...) and vector images (ai, cdr, ...) and many more are displayed in File Explorer's preview pane. This causes slowdowns, if a large docx or pdf file is read automatically for preview at folder opening. Can I selectively set which file extensions to preview (e.g. images only)?

Comment: You can also just disable the previewpane and only enable it when you actually need it. Its only one button in the toolbar. If you set the icons to large thumbnails in the views menu, you can preview images, but documents etc that still need the preview pane are not previewed.

Comment: @LPChip That would be quite inefficient. Imagine you step through image files with the navigation buttons and expect to preview each pic. Then suddenly there is large doc that should not be automatically previewed, but windows loads it nevertheless.

Comment: That's why I mentioned, if you use large thumbnails, you have all images in one overview, all other files are shown as regular icons.  That's how I browse folders with a large amount of images. Just set thumbnail to large and scroll.

Comment: You can edit your registry to change whether a specific file type is associated with a preview handler. This post addresses a related, but different question https://superuser.com/questions/1224289/why-is-windows-10-explorer-preview-pane-not-showing-regular-txt-files. I am not adept enough to provide a solution, but I'm pretty sure the answer below stating this cannot be changed is inaccurate.

Comment: [How to Disable Preview for Certain File Types in Explorer Preview Pane](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disable-preview-pane-file-types-explorer/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no native option to change conditions when the preview will load or not load.

There is a program called [PreviewConfig](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/previewconfig-tool-registers-file-types-for-the-preview-pane-in-windows-vista/) where you can select which filetypes will have an preview, but not disable it on larger files.

Comment: This does the job, thanks. Let me test it a bit.

Comment: [How to Disable Preview for Certain File Types in Explorer Preview Pane](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disable-preview-pane-file-types-explorer/)