Disable the VS Code preview pane integration in Windows Explorer
Whenever I select a file while the preview pane is active, VS Code tries to display it. How can I get rid of this integration? I searched around but strangely didn't see any trace of this feature being mentioned online.


How do you know that it is VS Code providing this integration and not, say, Notepad++ or Git or something else? I think this information may help us narrow down your problem and get you an answer.

This question goes over enabling previews for code file types, and using this info you could see what the preview handlers are for this .js file: https://superuser.com/questions/1320812/how-to-make-windows-explorer-preview-scripts-and-other-text-files

@music2myear I'm almost certain it's the VS Code's editor by the appearance and the sluggishness. Notepad++ uses Scintilla so it's a huge difference. But you're right, there could be other programs using the VS Code editor to provide this integration. I'll investigate others.

@music2myear Thanks I tried that, got a CLSID, but only led to a name of "Plain Text persistent handler". However in another answer in that question PowerToys was mentioned as a preview handler, so I checked and indeed it was the culprit all along.

Turns out it was PowerToys....

